# Pass data to VC when google maps marker is selected Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api

Im using the Google Maps SDK in my iOS app (in Swift) which presents a marker on the location that a user searches for (using the Google Places API), when a user then selects that marker it presents a new view controller to the screen, the problem I'm having is passing data (co-ordinates of the marker) to the new View controller (which for argument sake wants to print them to the console).

Here's the code to place a maker on the map (I'm using GooglePlaceAutocomplete - https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete):

```
// Allows user to search in search box from googlePlacesApi, when place is selected marker is placed
func placeSelected(place: Place) {
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    place.getDetails { details in
        latitude = details.latitude
        longitude = details.longitude

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        self.placeViewClosed()
        self.placeMarker(location)
    }
```

And here's the code from the Google maps view controller to present the new view when a marker is selected:

```
// executes when user taps custom window info above marker, presents PopooverViewController
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {
    let popoverContent = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover"))! as UIViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,300)
    popover!.delegate = self
    popover!.sourceView = self.view
    popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've tried using protocols but i just can't seem to pass the data! If anyone has any idea (in Swift) how to pass the data that would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

In my fun placeSelected I'm now using NSUserDefaults such as:

```
func placeSelected(place: Place) {
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    place.getDetails { details in
        latitude = details.latitude
        longitude = details.longitude
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        self.placeViewClosed()
        self.placeMarker(location)
    }
```

And I'n my new VC I'm using:

```
let latitude:Double =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("latitude") as! Double
let longitude:Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("longitude") as! Double
```

Is this an acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: why don't you use segue?

Comment: I tried but it presented errors regarding the window hierarchy and then for some reason I couldn't change the navigation bar attributes (such as title, colour etc) in the new view using the code i was using previously

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a segue and trigger it programmatically on:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!)
```

you can trigger it using:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUE_ID", sender: self)
```

then set whatever properties you want in the view controller here:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) 
{
    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController
}
```

Comment: I tried but it presented errors regarding the window hierarchy and then for some reason I couldn't change the navigation bar attributes (such as title, colour etc) in the new view using the code i was using previously

Comment: Then your bug isn't here, look again at your hierarchy and make sure every thing is right

Comment: hmm well i think i may have found an answer (see edit in original question) and I'm new (wish) to swift soo ill do some research and look at the view hierarchy, thanks!

Comment: Not the best solution, If I were you, I will invest some time now investigating what's wrong before it become a more complex bug which affect more than just passing a parameter to your VC!